# Issue with PDO select query: unknown error

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to get comfortable with **PDO** but can't get this to work.

Below is a script for a **basic search box:**

```
<?php
$sth= new connection();

if (isset($_GET['search'])) {

   $search_query = $_GET['search'];
   $search_query  = htmlentities($search_query);

   $result=$sth->con->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname  FROM users WHERE
       firstname LIKE '%" . $search_query . "%' OR
       lastname LIKE '%" . $search_query . "%' OR
       LIMIT 25");

  $result->bindParam(1, $search_query, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);     

  foreach ($result as $row) {
  $firstname = $row["firstname"];
  $lastname = $row["lastname"];


  if (!($result) == 0) {
  ?>
     <div="foo">Here are your results:</div>

  <?php
  } else {
  ?>

     <div="bar">No results!</div>
<?php
  }
}
?>
```

Here's the error that  I get:

`fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[]: <<Unknown error>>`

What am I doing wrong ?

ps: `$sth` works fine with other queries.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, typo, thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, you concat the sql string directly, so you don't need `bindParam`.
You should do something like:

```
$result=$sth->con->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname  FROM users WHERE
    firstname LIKE ? OR
    lastname LIKE ? OR
    LIMIT 25");
$result->bindValue(1, "%$search_query%", PDO::PARAM_STR);                     
$result->bindValue(2, "%$search_query%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

**Second**, you have to call `PDOStatement::execute` to execute the statement.

```
$result->execute();
```

**Third**, there are still small problems here and there, try read the manual and check the example...

Answer (score 2):

Right order and `execute` is required

```
$con = new PDO('...');
$stmt = $conn->prepare('...');
$stmt->bindParam('...');
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $row) {
    //...
}
```

[PDO Connection](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php), [PDO Prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), [PDO Bind](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), [PDO fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) and a [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/).